# Shower/Tub caulk cracking on new bathroom shower

Tags: shower, caulk

We had our bathroom remodeled recently and I noticed the caulk starting to crack around the tub. Upon further investigation it seems this caulk is very poor quality and dissolves when wet.

Are there any good quality bath/shower caulks that are not 100% silicone? I really don't like the shiny look of silicone and it attracts dirt quickly.

[image]Another tile contractor used a nice caulk (looks like sanded grout) in my other shower that was color matched to the grout but I can't find it available any the big box stores. The brand is c-cure http://www.flooringsupplyshop.com/setting-materials-n-more-83/grout-caulk-thinset-n-more-142/c-cure-caulk-sanded-986-793.html

I'm very hesitant to redo this until I find the right caulk. I'd appreciate any recommendations for a high quality non-shiny caulk that doesn't crack. Thanks

Comment: I purchased the locktite polyseamseal tub/shower. The guys at the local specialty hardware recommended and has good reviews on Amazon. It dries really hard. I suppose silicone would be ok in the shower since it should not get dirty with constant water exposure. I'll report back when I complete the job

Answer (score 1):

Latex is another common caulking material. Sounds like you're looking for something like this:

http://www.homedepot.com/p/Custom-Building-Products-Polyblend-09-Natural-Gray-10-5-oz-Sanded-Ceramic-Tile-Caulk-PC0910S/100678060

Comment: That would be exactly what I'm looking for however they say "Do not use in areas with constant water exposure"